# Sporadic java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on WFS transaction insert request

Tags: gis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am running GeoServer in a Tomcat container on-top of PostGIS, and inserting a single point (at a time) into the database using an OpenLayers 3 WFS transaction (xml in an AJAX POST).  The workspace is mypoints, the store is my_points.  Here is the Javascript:

```
// MY_POINT LAYER
var mypointssource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mypoints/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mypoints:my_points&srsname=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=application/json',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var mypoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: mypointssource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 8,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'yellow'})
        })
    })
});

// DRAW_PNT LAYER
var drawpntsource = new ol.source.Vector();

var drawpnt = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: drawpntsource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 3,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'red'
            })
        })
    })
});

// MAPQUEST TILE LAYER
var tile = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
});

// THE VIEW
var pointview = new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 16
});

// THE MAP
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [tile, mypoints, drawpnt],
    view: pointview
});

// REFOCUS VIEW ON MYPOINTS +/- SOME PADDING
mypointssource.on('change', function(e) {
    if (mypointssource.getState() == 'ready') {
        var paddedExtent = [];

        ext = mypointssource.getExtent();
        var dX = 0.08 * (ext[2] - ext[0]);
        var dY = 0.08 * (ext[3] - ext[1]);

        paddedExtent.push(ext[0] - dX);
        paddedExtent.push(ext[1] - dY);
        paddedExtent.push(ext[2] + dX);
        paddedExtent.push(ext[3] + dY);

        pointview.fit(paddedExtent, map.getSize());
    }
});

// DRAW INTERACTION
var entry = {};
var drawbutton = $('#draw');
var drawinteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: drawpntsource,
    type: 'Point'
});

// DRAW TOGGLE BUTTON:
var active = false;
function toggleDraw() {
    if (active == false) {
        map.addInteraction(drawinteraction);
        active = true;
    } else {
        map.removeInteraction(drawinteraction);
        active = false;
    }
}
// ADD EVENT HANDLER TO BUTTON
drawbutton.on('click', toggleDraw);

// WFS TRANSACTION FORMAT OBJ
var wfst = new ol.format.WFS({
    featureNS: 'mypoints',
    featureType: 'my_points',
    schemaLocation: "http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/wfs.xsd \
        http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd \
        http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mypoints/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?" + 
        "typename=mypoints:my_points"
});

// ON DRAW END
drawinteraction.on('drawend', function(evt) {
    map.removeInteraction(drawinteraction);
    drawbutton.hide();
    var newpoint = evt.feature;
    newpoint.set('the_geom', newpoint.getGeometry());
    newpoint.set('geometry', null);
    newpoint.set('title', "A generic title");
    var node = wfst.writeTransaction([newpoint], null, null, {
        gmlOptions: {srsName: "EPSG:3857"},
        featureNS: "mypoints",
        featureType: "my_points"
    });

    $('#messagebox').text(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node));

    // THE WFS AJAX TRANSACTION REQUEST:
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mypoints/wfs",
        data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node),
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        success: function(data) {
            var result = wfst.readTransactionResponse(data);
            $('#messagebox').text(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            var errorMsg = e ? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
            $('#messagebox').text(errorMsg);
        },
        context: this
    });
});
```

This works ~80% of the time, and sporadically, related to nothing I have been able to identify for 3+ days, it causes this server error:

```
06 Feb 15:18:00 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 Feb 15:18:00 WARN [geotools.xml] - Schema location not specified as namespace/location pair. Ignoring http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mypoints/wfs/DescribeFeatureTypetypename=mypoints:my_points
06 Feb 15:18:00 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@59fa8bfc
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor224.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:845)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:275)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am new to GeoServer, and I imagine that the issue is in the way I am forming the request.  Either the URL or something to do with the XML schema, but for the life of me I can't figure out how, or why it works sometimes and not others.

**Note:** The *Schema location not specified as namespace/location pair* warning at the top occurs even on successful transactions, and I don't think it is the direct cause, though if someone know's what that is about, that's another issue...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115471/qgis-wfs-error-could-not-commit-changes-to-layer) answer very helpful.  To paraphrase: basically, when GeoServer goes to get the XML schema definitions as listed in *schemaLocation*, if a .xsd file resides on that same server itself (e.g. it is accessible as a DescribeFeatureType request, as I had done in my ol.format.WFS options) it first checks the host name of the url against a list of known hosts.  **However**, due to an alleged bug it does not recognize itself when it is referenced as "localhost", and thinking it is someone else it shoots itself a GET request for the file.  It then spawns a thread to handle this GET request, which competes for access to the schema file with the initial thread.  Thus, an occasional deadlock.

I have fixed this by removing the DescribeFeatureType url from the *schemaLocation* attribute of the transaction XML.